# Minimizing the difference between two distributions with TensorFlow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, statistics, autoencoder

Suppose that the encoding neural network of a variational autoencoder (VAE) outputs a distribution from which latent samples will be drawn. To do this, the layer `tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL` is used. A decoding neural network takes this latent sample `z` and attempts to reconstruct the input (`x`) passed to the encoder.

In this VAE adaptation, the reconstructed input `x_tilde` is then again passed to the encoder, resulting in another latent sample  `z_tilde`. The goal of this VAE is to minimize the difference between `z` and `z_tilde`. This has readily been attempted by [Gauerhof & Gu](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_WACV_2020/papers/Lydia_Reverse_Variational_Autoencoder_for_Visual_Attribute_Manipulation_and_Anomaly_Detection_WACV_2020_paper.pdf), who named this technique the "reverse VAE". However, to minimize the aforementioned difference, they merely minimize the mean squared error (MSE) between the latent samples and try to reduce the variance of the latent samples to 1.

Considering the output of `tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL` is a distribution, it seems that we are able to use more accurate probabilistic methods than merely reducing the MSE between samples of the distribution. To attempt this, currently I am trying to maximize the covariance between distribution `z` and `z_tilde`, but I am unsure whether this is a robust technique mathematically. Another possibility would be minimizing KL-divergence, but somehow `D_kl(z||z_tilde)` returns extremely high values (even infinity) when using `tfp.distributions.kl_divergence`.

**TLDR:**
Is there a proven or correct deep learning method for minimizing the difference between two distributions?